# Saving text as HTML from form

Tags: html, asp.net

I have a form with a text field that users input text into. They can use multiple lines, put in bold text, underlined text, etc., but the text, when saved to SQL Server doesn't have any formatting saved, just the text is saved. What is the best way to save the text with the HTML so that when it gets viewed by another user and pulled up from Sql Server the HTML is saved and the formatting is saved?

Ex.

**hello**

Paul

This would be saved as

**hello**
Paul

you can't see it but there are  bold and carriage return html tags rapped around the text

Comment: I'd advise against letting user enter pure HTML, it can open can of worms. Use either bb-code or markdown like SO does - and interpret into HTML when displaying.

Answer (score 1):

When receiving data from the user, on the server side code, use HTML encode to safely store the data:

```
var inputData = Server.HtmlEncode("<strong>some data input from user</strong>"); //insert your user input data variable here
```

Then when displaying the data in your cshtml page, decode the data to display it as the user entered it:

```
HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(saveUserDataFromDatabaseVariable);
```

All this is assuming you have a rich text editor being plugged into the input field. CKEditor and TinyMCE are good ones.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a text editor. Take a look at [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/). It's free and easy to use :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you post some code and more details?

I have had good success with  [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/). It is customizable, and its content can easily be saved via postback to a standard `asp:TextBox`.

It is possible that the editor you are using is not actually updating the input/textarea that you are using, it may be cloning the text and drawing the formatting in an overlay. You can use developer tools, or javascript, to verify this by checking the `value` property of the input or textarea element. If it is being saved via AJAX or javascript the code may be using the `textContent` or `innerText` properties instead of `innerHTML`.

Answer (score 0):

I used the richtexteditor dll that's free online. it gave me a wiziwig box that the user can edit texxt in.